# numeros primos entre uma sequencia

Tags: c

O problema é o seguinte, tenho que receber um valor inteiro e calcular o fatorial desse numero (até ai tranquilo), e pegar  e printar na tela os numeros primos que existem entre um e o fatorial, porém estou com problemas para fazer isso, alguem pode me falar o que está errado?

```
/*Mostrar todos os numeros primos*/
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  long int numero,fatorial=1;
  int cont,contador=1,teste,truvs,bash=0,primo;

  scanf("%ld",&numero);

  for(cont=1;cont<=numero;cont++)
  {
    fatorial*=cont;
  }

  printf("FATORIAL -> %ld\n",fatorial);//só printei pra testar a fatoração
//---------DELIMITA A OPERAÇAO---------
  for(contador=2;contador<=fatorial;contador++)
  {
    bash=0;

//--------TESTA  PRIMO------------
    for(teste=1;teste<=contador;teste++)
    {
      bash=0;
//---------ISOLAR O TESTE DE DIVISAO-----------
      while(bash<2)
      {

        // truvs=contador%teste;
        if(contador%teste==0)
        {
          bash++;
           printf("%d\n",bash);
        }
        else
        {
          break;
        }


      }

      if(bash==2)
      {
        printf("%d\n",contador);
      }
      // bash=0;

    }
  }



return 0;
} //Fim do programa
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu teste para verificar se é primo está errado. Tente:

```
for (teste=1;teste<=contador;teste++)
{
  bash=0;
  div = 1;
  while(div <= teste)
  {
    if (teste%div == 0)
    {
       bash++;
    }
    div++;
  }
  if (bash==2)
  {
    printf("%d\n", teste); /* teste é primo */
  }
}
```

Obs: pode ser otimizado.